# How do I add a jquery-terminal to a view in my c# ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-terminal

Aside from some simple introductory tutorials and messing around with the default template, this is my first ever ASP.NET app and I'm a bit overwhelmed with all of the configurations, folders, features. I want to add the jquery terminal found here
https://terminal.jcubic.pl/
to one of my html pages, however the instructions on how to do that aren't very helpful. Where do I even unzip / install it once it's downloaded? And once that's in the right place, how do I reference it / include it in an html page? Does it need to go in a bundle? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I hope someone does help you. But this site is intended for very specific questions; not general question like this; how to use a technology. I have been in your situation many times and it's no fun. My recommendation is to train yourself on asp.net, javascript, bundling, ... from sites such as pluralsight, udemy, youtube, ....

Comment: This is probably same basic issue like any other JavaScript library, or any static webapp with ASP.NET if you figure out how to make it work with static CSS/HTML/JS files you will be able to make it work with any JavaScript including jQuery Terminal.

Comment: This may be give you some clue [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0) just search "static files ASP.NET".